# How to call Store Procedure within a package from Spring Integration

Tags: spring, stored-procedures, spring-integration

I am trying to call a store procedure that is inside a oracle package. The procedure accepts 5 IN parameters and it has one Out parameter which is type as table of varchar. I have mentioned the xml setup that I done in the context file. It is as follows

```
<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway
    id="storeprocref" data-source="dataSource" request-channel="RequestChannel"
    is-function="false" reply-channel="replyChannel"
     ignore-column-meta-data="true"
    stored-procedure-name="PKG_TEST.PR_CREATE_TEST"
    expect-single-result="false" >
    <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="USER" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
    <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="ID" direction="IN" type="INTEGER" />
    <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="ZONE" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR"/>
    <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="TEST_ID" direction="IN" type="INTEGER" />
    <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="APP_PARAMIN" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
    <int-jdbc:parameter name="USER" expression="payload"/>
    <int-jdbc:parameter name="ID" expression="payload"/>
    <int-jdbc:parameter name="ZONE" expression="payload"/>
    <int-jdbc:parameter name="TEST_ID" expression="payload"/>
    <int-jdbc:parameter name="APP_PARAMIN" expression="payload"/>
    <int-jdbc:returning-resultset name="P_LIST" row-mapper="com.local.mapper.TLISTRowMapper" />
```

But I am getting following error,

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1da205c': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: sp
ecify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:239) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114) [spring-beans-4.
0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1017) [spring-beans-4.0
.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELE
ASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEAS
E.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:276) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.
```

Can anyone please help me here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that the whole stacktrace?

Comment: Looks like you have correct configuration. I'd say that this StackTrace ins't related. Please, show more StackTrace.

Comment: A bit late - but to my knowledge `jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway` does not support Oracle packages. Instead you could create a service-activator bean using `SimpleJdbcCall` to do the job. The `withCatalogName()` method of `SimpleJdbcCall` will be understood to refer to the package name.